# Hadoop :how to set more than one column as a key and more than one column as a value in mapreduce classes in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, hdfs

i want to set more than one column as a key  and more than one column as a value in mapreduce "key-value pairs" classes in Hadoop using java and the file reads from contains 20 column .thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine all the columns which you wanna emit as key and value into a delimited string and emit them as Text.

Suppose your input looks like this :

No,Name,Age,Country

1,tariq,25,india

2,samy,25,xyz

And you want to emit "No+Age" as the key and "Name+Country" as the value.

```
public static class MyMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

        String line = "";
        String val = "";
        String[] parts;
        String key = "";

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            line = value.toString();
            parts = line.split(",");
            key = parts[0] + "." + parts[2];
            val = parts[1] + "." + parts[3];
            context.write(new Text(key), new Text(value));
        }
}
```

Comment: Please let know what is wrong with the answer so that i don't repeat the mistake. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a composite object which `implements WritableComparable<YourClassName>` to store the keys together in a concise form. See [this link](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/hadoop/9780596521974/serialization/id3548156) for a good example.

However, seeing as you want 20 components, I'd probably suggest just using a single `Text` object and parsing it when appropriate for that many. I often use tab separated values and parse them using a custom TSV parser, but merely splitting the `Text.toString()` with a suitable delimiter `char` should be entirely sufficient.